# Is there a way of removing grain from a cgi animation in after effects? (not the video kind.)

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have a blender animation fully rendered and imported into after effects and I want to try to remove as much noise and grain as much as possible.

However the type of noise that will be presented may be much different Than what you were expecting.

Here's an image of my blender animation:[image]

As you can see, The type of grain/noise is much more of pixels being mixed together rather than colorful blocky chunks of pixels.

I have already tried to use the Removal Grain effect from the effects at the top, but that proved to be ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the denoising method suggested by @CoinRocket, you could try to export the scene from Blender with less noise. If you have enough computation capacity, this will be a superior solution since post-denoising will always introduce some amount of blurriness into your video.

The noise in your example image looks like [fireflies](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Cycles_Fireflies), i.e. artifacts that stem from the nature of the [Cycles Engine](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/introduction.html) in Blender which is based on ray-tracing. There are several ways to reduce fireflies, however depending on your settings and available hardware render times will become *extremely* long. A while ago, I exported a 15-second sequence at 1000 samples and 24 frames per second rendered for three days straight on my laptop. So be warned.

The easiest way to reduce fireflies is to [increase the number of samples](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles) the program runs during export. This will correlate directly with rendering times.

There are several other settings that can affect the occurance of fireflies, but some of them are well-hidden. [Here's an explanation of some of them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-reduce-noise-in-cycles-render). There are also some tricks and workarounds that can help with that, [here's an article detailing some of them](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/). You might find some more on the [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) or through other sources. A while ago, I assorted some Tutorials on several techniques in Blender, [you can find it here](http://stuff.herebedragons.world/blender_tutorials.html). The titles are in German, but the links in the first tile on the left side might still be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try two approaches. One would be to use a plugin called denoiser by MagicBullet, which you have to buy. It does a terrific job but is painfully slow.

The second approach would be to export your sequence to a full resolution TIF sequence. Then use Photoshop's Image Processor, to batch the files-> running an action you create to apply the effect Despeckle.

You can try to export just a single frame, take it into Photoshop, and play with the Despeckle / Noise Reduction filters you have under the Noise drop down under effects, until you get the desired results. Then record the action of the final settings you feel look best.

Run Image Processor on your exported TIF sequence, saving back to TIF at same resolution, and have Image Processor run the action you recorded applying the filter settings you deemed best.

Judging by the image you provided, I would try Despeckle first, then add perhaps a very very small gaussian blur (very small like 0.1 or 0.2), then last, ADD noise to the image, use a very low variable, like 2 or 3, and use monochromatic noise (no color). Adding noise, a very small amount, will add a bit of texture to the image, much like film grain, and help mask out any little specks which might have been missed by the previous effects.

Again:  Despeckle -> Gaussian Blur 0.2ish -> Add Noise No Color Checked setting in the 2-4 range (setting may need to be higher if your image size is large, say 4k).

Record that, then process.

Take your TIF sequence processed through photoshop. Drag into PremierePro.  Set Still frame length to 1 Frame.

Create new sequence from 1 of the frames to match frame settings. Drage all your images to sequence. Render out as whatever you want. Then take back into AE if need be.